# Select multiple objects in Autodesk Forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

My Scenario :

I'm reading an IFC file ( using api/forge/modelderivative/modelViewProperties) and categorizing objects using the IFC type.

Therefore I need to select objects/highlight when you click on a particular type.

ex: if you click on type "IFCBUILDINGSTOREY" model should be able to highlight the child objects like level1,level2 etc ...

at the moment i tried both

```
viewerApp.getCurrentViewer().isolateById(idArray)

viewerApp.getCurrentViewer().select(idArray, Autodesk.Viewing.SelectionMode.REGULAR );
```

but nothing seems to be working... any advice ?

thanks

edit :

version

```
  <script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/6.*/viewer3D.min.js"></script>
```

and the JAVA SDK

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.autodesk</groupId>
            <artifactId>forge-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

I'm getting the properties using "forgeviewer/api/forge/modelderivative/modelViewProperties"

Comment: Can you please provide more information about your use case? What version of the viewer are you using? How exactly do you get the list of objects with the IFCBUILDINGSTOREY type (the `idArray`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different ways to search for objects with specific properties. Typically you can use the [search](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#search-text-onsuccesscallback-onerrorcallback-attributenames) method. This will return the IDs of all objects containing a specific phrase in one of its property names or property values. From this list you could then filter the objects further as needed, for example, by getting the properties of individual objects using the [getProperties](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#getproperties-dbid-onsuccesscallback-onerrorcallback) method, or by requesting the properties of several objects at once using the [getBulkProperties](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Model/#getbulkproperties-dbids-options-onsuccesscallback-onerrorcallback) method.

Once you have the IDs of the objects you are interested in, you can highlight them in different ways, for example, selecting them using the [select](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#select-dbids-model-selectiontype) method, or hide everything else but these objects using the [isolate](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#isolate-node-model) method.

Comment: Yes I tried both the methods you have mentioned , if you can see I have copied the code in the original post. Only issue is it is not getting highlighted when you pass an array , works for single Id.

Comment: That's why I was asking about the version of the viewer you're using. In the latest version (7.*), the [isolate](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#isolate-node-model) method supports both a single number as well as an array of numbers.

Comment: That's a really old version, and it's possible that isolating multiple objects was not available back then.

Comment: JAVA SDK of Autodesk: com-autodesk-client version 1.0.1 has being used ,  i will try to migrate the version , thank you

Comment: Hi actually I'm using V6* 

  <script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/6.*/viewer3D.min.js"></script>